# SQL - Select from column A grouped on two elements from column B

Tags: sql, select

I got an SQL database with data like this:

```
A | B
-----
q | 1
w | 2
q | 2
w | 3
e | 1
e | 2
e | 3
```

I want to see how many times different rows from A with the same value have different values in B. That is the pair of 1 and 2 was for q and e, so I want to have 2. So the result must look like:

```
1, 2 | 2        (q and e have 1 and 2)
1, 3 | 1        (only e has both 1 and 3)
2, 3 | 2        (w and e have both 2 and 3)
```

I wrote the following SELECT, but it is wrong:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d1.b AS b1, d2.b AS b2, COUNT(d1.a) 
FROM (SELECT a, b FROM data GROUP BY b) as d1, data as d2
GROUP BY b1, b2 
HAVING b1 <> b2
```

Comment: what is your rdbms?  Sql Server, Postgres ,,, ?

Comment: What is event and what is user? `[A] or [B]`

Comment: Sorry for misleading. Now i edited the question to match my own indications.

Comment: I think was better with `user and event` is more meaninfull than `A, B`. But is just me :)

Comment: Ok, you're right. So B is event that happens for different users. There's a lot of users and not so many events. I need to count how many times a pair of different events happened for users.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a self-join with aggregation:

Im using `[A] = user  [B] = event`

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/NSNKR77456)**

```
select d1.[event], d2.[event], count(distinct d1.[user]) num_user
from data d1 
join data d2
  on d1.[event] < d2.[event]
 and d1.[user] = d2.[user]   
group by d1.[event], d2.[event];
```

[image]